# PayPal API transaction refused on refund

Tags: php, paypal

This code does not work:

```
$sale = $this->get_sale($saleId);
$amt = $sale->getAmount();
$refund = new Refund();
$refund->setAmount($amt);
$refundSale = new Sale();
$refundSale->setId($saleId);
$refundedSale = $refundSale->refund($refund, $this->apiContext);
```

I tried not providing an Amount object to initiate a full refund, per https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/refund-payment/.

Yet this doesn't work either:

```
$sale = $this->get_sale($saleId);
$refund = new Refund();
$refundSale = new Sale();
$refundSale->setId($saleId);
$refundedSale = $refundSale->refund($refund, $this->apiContext);
```

Can anyone determine what I'm doing wrong? The API response doesn't give a lot of detail as to what is going on, just error code 400 and "The request was refused.{0}".

Comment: can you post the complete response from the PayPal that includes debug id?

Comment: a var_dump of the response yields: ``stdClass::__set_state(array( 'name' => 'TRANSACTION_REFUSED', 'message' => 'The request was refused.{0}', 'information_link' => 'https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#TRANSACTION_REFUSED', 'debug_id' => 'e5c656a198a83', ))``

Comment: Did you make sure that transaction is not already refunded ?

Comment: Yes it was not already refunded. It works if ``$amt`` is set manually. But setting it to the Amount in $sale doesn't work? It makes no sense.

Comment: Here is an article for the refunding through php api. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/05/paypal-refund-transaction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the debug_id, the transaction has already been fully refunded, so you get such error message. You can create a new transaction, then try to refund again for testing.